# Access/copy contents of preview window of fzf

Tags: fzf

Is it possible access/copy the contents of the preview window of fzf?
For example this code creates a list consisting of the top ten lines of a few selected files:

```
find -type f | fzf --multi --preview='head -10 {+}'
```

But I don't seem to be able to access/copy that window. All gets lost when I terminate fzf.

Answer (score 0):

I believe fzf is intended as an interactive tool, so you're not supposed to try and read the display directly. If you check `tldr fzf`:

```
$ tldr fzf

  (...)

  Select multiple files with `Shift + Tab` and write to a file:

      find path/to/directory -type f | fzf --multi > path/to/file

   (...)
```

So *after* you select the files (or one file with enter) it will be printed to stdout where you can pipe it to other programs.

If you just want everything from fzf's list without the hassle of shift+tab'ing each one, you could just skip fzf and do `find -type f | head -10 {+}`.

If you want the original input, but sorted according to fzf's rules, I'm not sure how to do that. Maybe the manual says, or perhaps it could be a feature request.

I use https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/ as my terminal and it has a nice feature where I can press a key and have the terminal itself send a line to the clipboard (`map ctrl+shift+p>l kitten hints --type line --program @`) or open the terminal scrollback in a text editor (`map ctrl+shift+f12 launch --stdin-source=@screen_scrollback kate --stdin`). That sounds more like what you're trying to do, but you can only do it with kitty, not other terminals.